# Issue while sending file content from filebeat to logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am new to ELK and i am trying to do some handson using the ELK stack. I am performing the following on WINDOWS,
    1. Installed Elastic search,confirmed with http://localhost:9200/
    2. Installed logstash,confirmed using http://localhost:9600/ 
       logstash -f logstash.config

```
    logstash.config file looks like this,
    input {
        beats {
            port => "5043"
        }
    }
    # The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
    # optional.
    # filter {
    #
    # }
    output {
        elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
    }


 3. Installed Kibana, confirmed using http://localhost:5601

    Now, i want to use filebeat to pass a log file to logstash which parses and forwards it to Elastic search for indexing. and finally kibana displays it.

    In order to do that, 
"

i did the following changes in filebeat.yml.
change 1 :
In Filebeat prospectors, i added 
paths:
    # - /var/log/*.log
     - D:\KibanaInput\vinod.log
Contents of vinod.log: Hello World from FileBeat.

Change 2:
In Outputs,
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
   hosts: ["localhost:9600"]

when i run the below command,
filebeat  -c filebeat.yml -e

i get the below error,
ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): Failed to parse JSON response: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type struct { Number string }

Please let me know what mistake i am doing.
```

Comment: did you add - input_type: log ?

Comment: yes. In filebeat.yml, its there..

Comment: I modifed logstash.config file as below,                                             
  input {
    beats {
 input_type: log 
        port => "5043"
    }
}
 filter {
  grok {
      match => ["message"]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
}                                                                                                           
  and modified contents of vinod.log as ,                         
   "message":"Hello World from FileBeat" ..  Now i dont see any error. But i dont see the contents reflecting in kibana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a good path.

Please confirm the following:

1. in your filebeat.yml make sure that you don't have comment in  the **output.logstash:** line, that correspond to your change number 2.
2. Make sure your messages are been grok correctly. Add the following output in your logstash pipeline config file.

   output {
     stdout { codec => json }
   }

   3.Start your logstash in debug mode.

   4.If you are reading the same file with the same content  make sure you remove the registry file in filebeat. ($filebeatHome/data/registry)

   5.Read the log files.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. Yes the line output.logstash was commented and it works fine now.  I have a few doubts,

Comment: i am getting the below error now,        
2017/05/10 11:40:26.828016 single.go:91: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error

Comment: If i comment **output.logstash:** and just use **output.elasticsearch:**, then it works fine.Any change in log fine reflects in kibana.
But if i comment **output.elasticsearch:** and use **output.logstash:**, then i am getting below errors,
2017/05/10 12:12:29.767016 sync.go:85: ERR Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error
2017/05/10 12:12:29.767016 single.go:91: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error

Please let me know what mistake i am doing

Comment: Are you sure logstash is up and running ?
Do you see any log error in logstash logs ?
Do you install X-Pack ? or have any authentication from your filebeat to logstash?

Comment: OK . I found your problem . 
Just modify the following line **hosts: ["localhost:9600"]**  to **hosts: ["localhost:5043"]** in your filebeat.yml .

And please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Hi, Please let me know the reason for modifying the port number.

When i run logstash using the command - logstash -f logstash.config, i get the following log in the terminal.

**10:56:43.250 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}.**

So, this confirms that logstash is running on port 9600.

So in filebeat.xml, i can redirect the data collected by filebeat  to either elastic search or logstash. I am choosing logstash 
and the port should be 9600 nor 5043.. right? Please correct me if my understanding is right

Comment: One more thing i would like to mention. I have not installed the logstash-input-beats.i get connection refused error as below,                                                  **logstash-plugin install logstash-input-beats
ERROR: Something went wrong when installing logstash-input-beats, message: Connection refused - Connection refused**                                                   Is this a prerequisite for what i am trying to do.

Comment: And,i get the following error if i change the port from 9600 to 5403,

2017/05/11 05:52:23.900894 log.go:91: INFO Harvester started for file: D:\KibanaInput\test1.log
**2017/05/11 05:52:30.997894 single.go:140: ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): dial tcp [::1]:5403: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

Comment: 1 - By default the beats input comes with logstash.
2 - By default the **monitoring api** of logstash binds to 9600.
3 - The 5043 port or 5044 are the ones used by the filebeat plugin, over the lumberjack protocol that uses tcp. I'm not sure but I believe that the ports are default for the lumberjack protocol used by filebeat. 


Make sure your logstash is running, check if the logstash is using the port 5043 or 5044. 

Are you running everything in the same machine ? or in a distribution environment?

Comment: I am running everything on same machine as of now. Once it works here, i will go to distributed environment.

Comment: OK. great!

Lets see what is happen.
Start logstash in debug mode : **bin/logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --config.reload.automatic** 

and Start filebeat in debug mode too : **./filebeat -e -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -d  ̈publish ̈**

See if you getting any error. 

If not see what port logstash is listening :  netstat -a

Comment: 1.In my logstash, i am using port 5043 for beats as shown below, 11:58:53.385 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.inputs.beats - Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5043"}In filebeat.yml also i used ,**output.logstash:#The Logstash hosts hosts: ["localhost:5043"].** Is this right? .. but i dont see any logs reflecting there. 2.One more thing i tried, Instead of logstash, i redirected filebeat output to elasticsearch(running on port 9200), **output.elasticsearch:# Array of hosts to connect to.hosts: ["localhost:9200"]** and it works. I can see logs in Kibana.

Comment: 3.Similarly, if u comment out elasticsearch and redirect filebeat output to logstash(running on port 9600),
i should use the below,
**output.logstash:#The Logstash hosts hosts: ["localhost:9600"]**
I am still confused why should i use,
**output.logstash:#The Logstash hosts hosts: ["localhost:5403"]**

Comment: In logstash.config file, beat port is 5043. Now for further investigation, In filebeat.yml ,  should  i use **output.logstash:#The Logstash hosts hosts: ["localhost:9600"]** or **output.logstash:#The Logstash hosts hosts: ["localhost:5403"]**

Comment: Use 5403, not 9600.

Can you please past here the output of your console after starting logstash in debug mode.

Comment: I started logstash in debug mode using the below command,
logstash -f logstash.config --debug 
and i found grokparsefailure issue,

14:05:24.559 [[main]>worker3] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - output received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-05-11T08:35:19.297Z, "offset"=>356, "@version"=>"1", "beat"=>{"hostname"=>"AAEINBLR02717D", "name"=>"AAEINBLR0
2717D", "version"=>"5.4.0"}, "input_type"=>"log", "host"=>"AAEINBLR02717D", "source"=>"D:\\KibanaInput\\test1.log", "message"=>"ELK165 ELKMessage", "type"=>"log", "tags"=>["beats_input_codec_plain_applied", "_gro
kparsefailure"]}}

Comment: Then i just removed the filter part from logstash.config and reran and i dont see any grokparsefailure,
14:00:41.470 [[main]>worker4] DEBUG logstash.pipeline - filter received {"event"=>{"@timestamp"=>2017-05-11T08:30:35.398Z, "offset"=>261, "@version"=>"1", "input_type"=>"log", "beat"=>{"hostname"=>"AAEINBLR02717D
", "name"=>"AAEINBLR02717D", "version"=>"5.4.0"}, "host"=>"AAEINBLR02717D", "source"=>"D:\\KibanaInput\\test1.log", "message"=>"ELK15 ELKMessage", "type"=>"log", "tags"=>["beats_input_codec_plain_applied"]}}
 Still I  dont see logs reflecting in kibana.

Comment: input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
    }
}
# The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
# optional.
# filter {
#  grok {
#     match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{DATA:message}" }
#    }
#}
output {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
}
This is my logstash.config now

Comment: OK.! Great .
Confirm one thing. There is no errors when started in debug mode?

Show me one line of logs from your log file.

Comment: These are the errors i see when i run,
**logstash -f logstash.config --debug --verbose**

**ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /Softwares/ELK/logstash-5.3.2/logstash-5.3.2/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console**

Comment: You can ignore that for now. 

any errors in filebeat? if not I believe you can start indexing the logs . 
Whats the problem now? 

The _grokfailure tag its because your grok pattern is wrong.

Comment: 1. There are no errors now.   No errros in filebeat also. But i dont see any logs reflecting in kibana.                                                                             2. I am not aware of indexing. Is it manadatory to do indexing in order to see logs reflecting in kibana? .                                                      
3.Cant we have some default indexing? .

Comment: OK! 
I believe the problem was solved. 
Please follow the steps bellow: 

1 - Remove the **registry** file inside your filebeat home directory. 
2 - Restart filebeat.
3 - Open Kibana, if you dont created a index before, kibana should ask you to do it. if there is no index, after open kibana you should be in **Management** - **index pattern** then just create a new one with the default logstash-*

Comment: But do we need to setup index pattern in kibana. Because from filebeat, if i direct send output to elastic search, kibana displays it. But if i am sending output to Logstash, then kibana doesnt display.

Comment: Do you try to remove the registry file in your filebeat home directory ?
OR just create a new log file and make filebeat read the new file . 

If you are reading the same file and the same content filebeat save the state of the file in the registry file, and just read the file once, or when the size of the same is changed.

Comment: 1.Yes.. i have removed the registry file from filebeat home.                                   2. I edited the current file and also tried by creating a new file also.In both cases, the output from logbeat comes to logstash. But i dont see anything is kibana.

Comment: Ok ! 
I believe there is something you are not saying. 
But try the following : remove all data in elasticsearch
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/logstash-*'    . and than refresh
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_refresh'

Comment: i removed the elasticservice and restarted it.  one thing which i would like to remention is that, **logstash-plugin install logstash-input-beats** is not performed. It gives me some **Connection refused** error. Is it ok?

Comment: Its working fine now. In kibana->management->index patterns, instead of **logstash-***, **filebeat-*** was set as default index. Not sure why i did that. Anyways, thanks a lot for the help. May i have your mail id please

Comment: give me your email . I send you my. 

Please mark as correct please . :)

Comment: hy.vinod88@gmail.com.. Please send me a mail .

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to mark answer as useful . :)